# EXTJS6 : Application does not load the screens after generating Production/Testing build and deployed it to Tomcat

Tags: javascript, tomcat, extjs, extjs5, sencha-cmd

I created an application using EXTJS6 and sencha cmd 6.2.15.

This application works fine on sencha cmd but while I am generating the Testing or Production build and deploy it on Tomcat, It fails to render my viewport.

> Let me elaborate more on "Fails to load the viewport"

Below is my code inside app.js's launch method,

launch: function() {

**// Service calls here - Getting successful**

```
            /**
            * viewport rendering
            */

            Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
                layout: 'border',
                items: [
                    {
                        region: 'north',
                        xtype: 'headerView',
                        cls: 'header'
                    },
                    {

                        region: 'center',
                        autoScroll: true,
                        width: screen.width,
                        xtype: 'contentview'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'footerView',
                        cls: 'footer',
                        height: 28,
                        region: 'south'
                    }
                ],
                listeners: {
                    afterrender: function() {
                        var me = this;
                        console.log('after render'); // **Never executed in Prod build or testing** 

                    }
                }
```

Please note, the afterrender function is never executed in PROD or Testing build. I am generating Testing build using `sencha app build -c testing`

Please note, I did not specifically made any changes in app.json for PROD or QA builds. I have no clue why my viewport is not rendered.

When I run this using the sencha cmd it works like a charm. Only difference for Tomcat is I created a WAR using PROD build and deployed to /webapps folder

I do not see any errors on the console on IE or FF. Any clue or pointers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you copy the generated build files from `builds/production` to the webapp root (the same folder, that `index.html` is in)?

Comment: Can you grep through the production's app.js to see whether the viewport is created? Because maybe Cmd didn't compile that part of the code into the app.js

Comment: @Gašper : Yes, I copied the generated files from build/production and created a war using it and deployed the WAR inside the webapps folder in tomcat.

Comment: @Alexander : THere is no viewport being created at all when I inspected the DOM in the broswer.

Comment: Do you see `app.js` load in Developer Tools Network tab?